# Compiler: "error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type" in thread application

Tags: c, multithreading, pointers, struct, argument-passing

Its my first publication and I'm studying C programming right now so I'm not an expert.

I've encountered that error compiling this lines (in a thread):

```
...
struct task_par *tp;
tp = (struct task_par *)arg;
a = tp->arg;
...
```

struct task_par is:

```
typedef struct
{
    int arg;
    int period;
    int priority;
} task_par;
```

Note that "arg" is the argument of the thread

What's the correct type of "a"? because I've tried every type and it's still "error", so what else is wrong?

Comment: Move the struct definition about the code that references the struct members.

Comment: @Doozer Post the *all* the relevant code, guessing the error is not fun...

Answer (score 1):

You don't define a `struct task_par` with the code you have shown. What you are defining is a `typedef` (a sort of new type) named `task_par` that is an alias for a certain anonymous struct type.

Your variable definition should simply say `task_par *tp;` in this case. If you prefer to use `struct task_par`, the way you have it now, you should change your struct definition to:

```
struct task_par
{ // ...
}
```

Or you can combine the two:

```
typedef struct task_par
{ // ...
} task_par_t;
```

Then you could define your variable either as `struct task_par *tp;` or as `task_par_t *tp;`.

The bottom line is that struct names and typedef names live in two different namespaces. You could even do `typedef struct foo { /* */ } foo;`, but some consider that bad form due to the potential for confusion...